# multiple if statements in javascript not acting as they should

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I'm creating a random image generator that displays images when a button is clicked. I'm trying to prevent the same image being displayed twice in a row by having the random number connected to each image increase by 1 if duplicated (in other words the next image will be shown rather than the same image twice).  I'm trying to use `if` statements to achieve this but there seems to be a glitch in my code as the same image is still being displayed more than once. Not sure where the problem is. Any solutions out there ? 
Thanks

```
document.getElementById('ranImgBtn').onclick = function() {

var ranImgDis = document.getElementById('ranImgDis');
  ranImgDis.style.width = '300px';
  ranImgDis.style.height = '200px';

var pic1 = href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/11268502654_f28f05966c_m.jpg";
var pic2 = href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/33/45336904_1aef569b30_n.jpg";
var pic3 = href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5211/5384592886_80a512e2c9.jpg"; 

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 +1)) + 1;

if(num !== 2 && num !== 3) {
      if(ranImgDis.src !== pic1) {
        ranImgDis.src = pic1; 
      } ranImgDis.src = pic2; 
} else if (num !== 1 && num !== 3) {
      if(ranImgDis.src !== pic2) {
      ranImgDis.src = pic2;
      } ranImgDis.src = pic3;
} else if (num !== 1 && num !== 2) {
      if(ranImgDis.src !== pic3) {
      ranImgDis.src = pic3;
    } ranImgDis.src = pic1;
} 
}
```

Comment: So do you have the same number of rows as you have images, or do you just don't want the same image in the next row, but the same image can appear in other rows etc?

Comment: That is some crazy cat logic you have going on there! Why not `if(num == 1)` etc.... not that if statements are the best way to do this

Comment: what is `href`? ` pic1 = href=`??

Comment: @hunter: Good point, but not the actual problem in the code. The `href` variable will just be assigned each of the URLs in turn, and then never used any more. Although that code is incorrect, it's not what keeps the code from working. The `href=` part of those statements should just be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work, and let you expand the number of images beyond three.

```
document.getElementById('ranImgBtn').onclick = function() {
  var ranImgDis = document.getElementById('ranImgDis');
    ranImgDis.style.width = '300px';
    ranImgDis.style.height = '200px';

    var pics = [ 
        "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/11268502654_f28f05966c_m.jpg",
        "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/33/45336904_1aef569b30_n.jpg",
        "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5211/5384592886_80a512e2c9.jpg"
    ]

    var currentSrc = document.getElementById('ranImgDis').src
    var newSrc = currentSrc

    while (newSrc == currentSrc) {
        newSrc = pics[Math.floor( Math.random() * pics.length )]
    }

    ranImgDis.src = newSrc
}
```

JSFiddle of it at http://jsfiddle.net/X7HM2/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `else` in all your inner `if` statements. The result is that even if the code in the `if` statement is executed, the code after it is always executed and replaces what the code inside the `if` statement did.

You code like this:

```
if(ranImgDis.src !== pic1) {
  ranImgDis.src = pic1; 
} ranImgDis.src = pic2;
```

should be:

```
if(ranImgDis.src !== pic1) {
  ranImgDis.src = pic1; 
} else {
  ranImgDis.src = pic2;
}
```

---

You can make the code simpler and more flexible by putting the images in an array, and keep the index of the current image rather than checking the source of the image. You can use the length of the array when you create the random number, then you can just add more images to the array without changing anything else in the code.

```
var pics = [
  "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/11268502654_f28f05966c_m.jpg".
  "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/33/45336904_1aef569b30_n.jpg",
  "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5211/5384592886_80a512e2c9.jpg"
];

var current = 0;

document.getElementById('ranImgBtn').onclick = function() {

  var ranImgDis = document.getElementById('ranImgDis');
  ranImgDis.style.width = '300px';
  ranImgDis.style.height = '200px';

  // get a random number within a range one less than the number of images
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pics.length - 1)) + 1;
  // use the random number to pick a different image from the current one
  current = (current + num) % pics.length;

  ranImgDis.src = pics[current]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you change the logic abit.
Rename the images to numbers from 1 to 3 .
Than generate the random number between 1 to 3 and if that random number is same as currently loaded image regenerate the number , this logic will help you even when you will add images from 3 to finite limit.

Comment: Could you provide a Javascript example of the solution your suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit messy, and also there are some obvious problems like:

```
if(ranImgDis.src !== pic1) {
    ranImgDis.src = pic1; 
} ranImgDis.src = pic2;
```

This will unconditionally set ranImgDis.src to pic2 at the end of the day. So maybe you should think this over. I suggest you to maintain an array instead to avoid dupes.